# Is there a way to flush the nuget index.json file cache in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have created a package and uploaded it to to our nuget feed and it all works fine, however, when I try to install it using visual studio nuget package manager, it tells me that the package can't be found in the index.json (even though it has let me pick the version in the drop down to install):

> Package 'Nuget.Group.Classes 2.0.0' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.

I'm guessing this is cached in that instance of visual studio as sometimes it will let me install the same package into another project in a different visual studio that is open at the same time and if I wait a random amount of length, the package will then install in the project that it wouldn't do in before.

Is there a way to refresh the cache so it gets the latest index.json file?  I tried shutting visual studio and reloading the project - this sometimes works but also sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much click around, I have found it:

Click on

> Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings

Under the general tab there is a button labelled

> Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear my package source index cache by doing the following. First, find out where your package cache is by running:

`nuget locals all -list`

You want the entry for `http-cache`. For me, the package source index was being cached here:

`%LocalAppData%\NuGet\v3-cache`

Then identify and the delete the folder for the package source that you want to refresh. It will look something like:
`xxxx$-PackageSourceName_nuget_v3_index.json`